# ASP.Net, MVC Entity Framework, Mapping 1 to many

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, mapping

In my project I'm using ASP.Net 4.0 Entity Framework database first.
I have 2 Entity classes with foreign key and View Model, sample below:

**fibre class:**

```
namespace fibresInTexilesMvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class fibre
    {


        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public fibre()
        {
            this.products = new HashSet<product>();
        }

        public int FiberId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Picture1 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Advantages { get; set; }
        public string Disadvantages { get; set; }
        public string Picture2 { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<product> products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**product class:**

```
    namespace fibresInTexilesMvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Overview { get; set; }
        public int FiberId { get; set; }

        public virtual fibre fibre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View Model.cs**

```
namespace fibresInTexilesMvc.ViewModels
{
    public class FibAndProdViewModel

    {
        public int FiberId { get; set; }
        public string Picture1 { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Advantages { get; set; }
        public string Disadvantages { get; set; }
        public string Picture2 { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to receive in ViewModel details about the selected fibre and all related products to this fibre.

In **Home Controller** I've created action method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using fibresInTexilesMvc.Models;
using fibresInTexilesMvc.ViewModels;


    {

            //GET: Home/FiberAndProducts/5
            public ActionResult FiberAndProducts(int? FiberId)
            {
                List<fibre> fibandprodlist = db.fibres.ToList();
                List<FibAndProdViewModel> fibandprodVmList = fibandprodlist
                            .Select(x => new FibAndProdViewModel()
                            {
                                FiberId = x.FiberId,
                                Picture1 = x.Picture1,
                                Description = x.Description,
                                Advantages = x.Advantages,
                                Disadvantages = x.Disadvantages,
                                Picture2 = x.Picture2,
                                Picture = x.products.Select(a => a.Picture).SingleOrDefault(),
                                Name = x.products.Select(a => a.Name).SingleOrDefault()
                            }).ToList();
                return View(fibandprodVmList);
            }

    }
```

When I open in browse it shows me below error:
[Error in program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX3jN.png)

is this error can be related with collection properties like 'Picture' and 'Name' ?.When I comment this two properties I can see all fibres from table, but it's not what I need. What I need is, when I press link with specific fibre it should show me in another View details about the fiber and fetch from db.products all related products.
I don't know how to solve this issue.
Below is :

```
@model IEnumerable<fibresInTexilesMvc.ViewModels.FibAndProdViewModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>FiberAndProducts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FiberId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Picture1)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Advantages)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Disadvantages)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Picture2)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Picture)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FiberId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Advantages)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Disadvantages)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture2)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

On top I have a question regard to pictures. To render pictures path from database to the View I'm using Custom HTMLHelper( @Html.Image(@Model.Picture1)). It showing pictures in 'Details' View, but when I use IEnumerable like in ViewModel it show me Compailer Error: "Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Picture1' and no extension method 'Picture1' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".
How can I use CustomHTMLHelper when I have IEnumerable or ICollection?.

Code for **CustomHtmlHelper.cs:**

```
namespace fibresInTexilesMvc.CustomHtmlHelper
{
    public static class CustomHtmlHelper
    {
        public static IHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string src)
        {
            //Build <img> tag
            TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("img");
            //Ad "src" attribute
            tb.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(src));
            //return MvcHtmlString. This class implements IHtmlString
            //interface. IHTMLString will not be html encoded.
            return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get that error if `SingleOrDefault` finds more than 1 record. So switch to FirstOrDefault or make sure only 1 (or no) record is returned.

Comment: Steve Greene thank you for response. I've checked "SingleOrDefault" and it fetching from product table only one 1tem, I need to fetch 3 of them to each fiber.

Comment: I handle my Error by removing from: retutrn View(db.fibres.ToList())

Comment: in 'Index ActionResult  ' .ToList()', but  still I have a problem to retrieve all related products with fibre and render picture.

Comment: One question per post please.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller this

```
Picture = x.products.Select(a => a.Picture).SingleOrDefault(),
Name = x.products.Select(a => a.Name).SingleOrDefault()
```

should change to

```
Products = x.products
```

In your FibAndProdViewModel add

```
ICollection<product> Products { get; set; }
```

Like this

```
namespace fibresInTexilesMvc.ViewModels
{
 public class FibAndProdViewModel
 {
    public int FiberId { get; set; }
    public string Picture1 { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Advantages { get; set; }
    public string Disadvantages { get; set; }
    public string Picture2 { get; set; }

    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    ICollection<product> Products { get; set; }
 }
}
```

And in the view this

```
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Picture)
</td>
<td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
```

should change to

```
<table>
 @foreach (var product in item.Products) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Picture)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Name)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: When I changed to 'List<product> Products = x.products', I have red line with comment 'Invalid initialized member declaration, so I add in Home Controller on the top 'private int products;' and is ok.

Comment: In my View after changes  to :'  @foreach (var product in item.Products) ' I receive red line in 'item' saying 'The name item does not exist in current context'. In ' @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => product.Name)' , I have red line in 'DisplayFor' with comment: "The type arguments for method 'Display extension.DisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper < TModel, Expression <Func < TModel, TValue >>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: I've make changes to my project and add "public ICollection<product> Products { get; set; }" to "FibAndProdViewModel.cs" and instead of "  
 Picture = x.products.Select(a => a.Picture).SingleOrDefault(),
  Name = x.products.Select(a => a.Name).SingleOrDefault() " in Controller I put "Products = x.products".

Comment: The autcome is that I can't see in my view properties like Picture and Name.